# first-time user logs in, show a dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The first time a user logs into my app, I'd like to show them a jQuery dialog with general information.

To check whether a user has logged in, I can check the last_login field in the mySQL database--if it's empty, then the user hasn't yet logged in.

I also know how to setup jQuery dialogs.

But I don't think I can use jQuery and mySQL together, so I'd like to know what others have used to solve this problem. I've looked at some of the other questions here on SO; haven't found any that put the first-time login and the popup together.

I'm using Codeigniter for my framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're validating login, just pass a parameter to the page saying that it's the first login.  So validate as normal, but just tell the page you get redirected to that it is the user's first time (via that mysql column).

The page you view when you successfully login will check to see if that parameter is passed and, if it is, will pop the modal.

Look here to read about modals: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/.  You can set the variable in session, as mentioned, or you could pass it as a querystring parameter.  You can use that variable to determine whether or not to fire the modal.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't understand how the modal is triggered. Is there a specific jQuery function you could point me to? I don't mind looking it up myself, but I want to understand it.

Comment: @chowwy I updated my answer to point you in the direction of some modal help.  Please let me know if this doesn't suffice.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I've read through the dialog documentation for other parts of the app; I still don't see what method you are suggesting to trigger the popup.

Comment: You can check the querystring values most easily, in this case, with PHP.  So, you could mingle the PHP and jQuery to check $_GET['some_value'].  Also, you could use some regex to fine some_value= in the URL.  I realize this can be seen as somewhat vague, but I'm unsure of your level of experience with PHP/jQuery/Javascript

Comment: I understand what you're saying--the issue for me is how to get the dialog to fire. Are you suggesting a GET function through, say, AJAX and then based on that value show the dialog? If so, I will give it a try. I've upvoted your answer, and will be back once I can confirm that this works.

Comment: You already must be doing something for validation, right? -- or is that done automatically by some CodeIgniter functionality?  I'm not saying that you need an AJAX call, although that would work.  I'm saying that when you're actually logging in, before redirecting to a successful login page, append a querystring value firstLogin=1.  In the Javascript for that page, check to see if this value is set to 1 or not.

Comment: Yes, I'm using an authentication library. I will give this a try and report back. I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a flag set in the session and use it as a identifier once the session is created.

The way to interact with database with JQuery is to use some persistent storage NOSQL Database like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)

Comment: I don't think the solution for interaction between jQuery and MySQL is Mongo.

Comment: But setting a session variable would be helpful if you need that information to be persistent across more than one page.

Comment: @tmjam Thank you for your response; I've heard that NoSQL works with jQuery, but I'm more comfortable with mySQL and won't be able to change the database at this point anyway.

Comment: @dweiss: It is not interaction with MySQL, just a suggestion to use MongoDB if we want JQuery to interact with Database

Comment: I understand, that's why I didn't downvote it.  I don't think it's a direct answer to the question so it wasn't upvoted -- I just wanted to explain that.  But I understand your comment and can understand the value in it.

Comment: @tmjam Thanks, because I appreciate all the answers I get. I realize this is voluntary!

Answer (score 0):

I believe codeigniter is php (not tagged) so just put the script to pop up a dialog inside a php if statement:

```
<?php if (fFirstTime) { ?>
<script>
  $("#dialogdiv").dialog({...options...});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Treat this as pseudocode because I'm sure it has errors but you get the idea.  fFirstTime would be from your db layer (model) in codeigniter.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it out; the dialog isn't firing. I'm using similar logic elsewhere in the app--it's integrating it with the popup that doesn't seem to be working.